# Correlational Meta-analysis

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, meta-analysis, group-differences

I conducted a correlational meta-analysis. There were three groups of behaviours and one aggregate effect size for the correlation between each behaviour group and a continuous measure. We used pearsons r as the effect size.

All three aggregate effect sizes are small, but one is still larger than the other two (.2 compared to .1). In the discussion we talk about how this may have implications moving forward in the field. But a reviewer has said that following:

“The authors imply they compared effect sizes between behaviours, but unless I missed it, they didn’t report an official statistical moderator analysis for that. They appear to be simply “eyeballing” the differences”

Is there a test to compare effect sizes in a case like this? Or is it sufficient to ‘eyeball’ the differences?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Meta-regression would give you an estimate of the difference with confidence interval.